Technique for Finding Primes
I found this interesting technique online to solve this problem.
Find all positive integers n for which $3n - 4, 4n - 5$, and $5n - 3$ are all prime numbers.
It is known that any prime number other than $2$ and $3$ must be congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $6$.

If $n ≡ 1\pmod 6$, then $5n - 3 ≡ 2 \pmod 6$, which is not a prime number.
Similarly, if $n ≡ -1 \pmod 6$, then $5n - 3 ≡ 4 \pmod 6$, which is not a prime number.

This tells us that n must be $2$ or $3$. At this point, we can simply try $2$ and $3 $ to see which one works.
If $2$ and/or $3$ were not among these prime numbers, how could I generalize this technique?

I don't understand.  You aren't told that $n$ is prime.

I suggest:  ignoring small $n$, we must have each of those terms congruent to either $\pm 1\pmod 6$ (possibly different signs amongst the three terms).  After checking the small $n$, explore the consequences of that.

Duplicate of Number of positive integers n such that 3n - 4, 4n - 5, 5n - 3 are all prime

$3n-4$ and $5n-3$ have opposite parity , so one of them must be $2$
